# Making Firebug break inside dynamically loaded javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm looking for a way to debug a dynamically loaded jQuery document.ready function.

Obviously I can't just bring up the script panel and add a breakpoint with the mouse since the function does not exist there.

I've also tried adding "debugger;" to the function (without the quotes), but that did not do anything. I have ensured that the function is actually executed while I tried this.

Thanks for your help,

Adrian

**Edit:** I just noticed that Firebug actually breaks on debug. However, when it does so on a dynamically loaded script, it does not bring up the source code of that script as usual. Plus, the call stack ends right below my own code. I can bring up the implementation for document.ready via the call stack, but that does not really help. Is this a Firebug bug or have I missed something?

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in Firebug for the domain from which your page loads (Console panel) ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also have no problems debugging the scripts on the page I am loading first, and that page is in the same domain. I just tried the "debugger;" statement there and it worked fine. So it seems that the "debugger" statment is just not working for dynamically loaded scripts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just worked on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874256/dynamicaly-loaded-js-function-does-not-appear-in-firebug-js-debugger/874400#874400). The solution involves adding the word debugger twice; once at the top of the external file and one more time at the top of the function that needs to be debugged.

I noticed that if the debugger word was used only once, it did not work. Example:

```
//myExternal.js
debugger;
function myExternalFunction(){
 debugger;
 /* do something here */
}
```

Comment: Update: Thankfully this bug has been long fixed in Firebug already. I haven't had to have to employ this trick for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

You might try placing a break point where the event is called, and then instead of click "Play", choose "Step Into" (F11). I don't have a test case in front of me, but I think this may work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever got this figured out, but in case someone else needs it...

I got around this by moving the code I wanted to debug to an external file that was linked from the main page.

In my case, I had default.aspx loading services.aspx into a content div using jQuery AJAX.  Services.aspx in turn, was loading jQuery UI tab elements using AJAX from a webservice that was providing it data.  The webservice code was in a file called data.js which was linked from default.aspx.  I needed to debug the code that was in the header of services.aspx (that loaded the tabs with data), but couldn't ever see it in any of the available inspectors.  I just moved the code I needed to a new function in data.js and called it from the header in services.aspx.

I hope that makes sense to someone who needs it!

Comment: Yes, that works fine. In my case the code was dynamically generated by the server though depending on other data in the same web request.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered same behavior (Firebug ignoring `debugger;` statement in dynamically loaded code) in **Firefox 5.0/Firebug 1.7.3**.

Worked around by detaching Firebug window ("Open Firebug in New Window").

Answer (score -2):

There's also a 'debugger' keyword that's supported by the IE JScript debugger, and Safari's Web Inspector, so i would be surprised ifit wasn't supported in firebug.

Basically:

```
// mydynamicallyloadedfile.js
... // do stuff
debugger; // triggers debugger
... // more stuff
```

And i would expect firebug to break at the `debugger` keyword

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I have already tried the debugger statement and while it usually works fine, it does not work in this case (details in my question).