# save the using in @using Moj.Tg.Gen.UI.Common;

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I created static method that will help me using js files (took the idea from him: https://stackoverflow.com/a/912989/289246).

```
@using Moj.Tg.Gen.UI.Common;
@section scripts {
    @JSHelper.JSBlock("/Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.js", "Scripts/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js")
    @JSHelper.JSBlock("/Scripts/plugins/jquery.form.wizard.js", "Scripts/plugins/jquery.form.wizard.min.js")
    @JSHelper.JSBlock("/Scripts/Pledges/create.js")
}
```

I want this to work without writing `@using Moj.Tg.Gen.UI.Common;` each place I am using it.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Web.config of the Views folder I added:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        ....
        ....
        <add namespace="Moj.Tg.Gen.UI.Common" /> //<-- Added this!
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```