# jQuery Ajax: Add JavaScript Reference to Page from .NET MVC Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I hope I am just missing something here, but I've been tearing my hair out over trying to include scripts from a .NET MVC Partial View when using jQuery Ajax to load the view.

I have a form whose HTML gets replaced via a callback function on a jQuery ajax get request:

```
$.get('/My/Partial/View', function(result) {
    $form.html(result);
});
```

The partial view contains several  tags, which are not being seen by the browser.  How can I use jQuery Ajax to load a partial view to the page in a way that the  tags are executed?

Comment: Is it calling your action method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912755/include-javascript-file-in-partial-views