# How to run javascript in a jsp file , which is included in other jsp pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a header.jsp file.I am including this file in the body of rest of the jsp pages i have.
I want this header.jsp file to contain a script for showing current date/time(for example). I wrote the script ,but it didn't work. So, i had to include that script in every jsp page , where i have included that. but, that is not a good idea,i know. please suggest a way out.

header.jsp:

```
<div id="header">
        <img id="main_logo" src="<c:url value="/resources/Images/logo.png" />">

        <div id="move_right">
        <div id="login_img">            
            <img id="user_img" src="<c:url value="/resources/Images/userlogo.png" />">                          
        </div>
        <div id="login_info">
            <span id="username">Administrator</span>
            <br>
            <span id="date_time"></span>
            <br>
            <span id="logout">Log Out </span>
            <span id="help">Help</span>
        </div>
        </div>
```

the script that i want is:

```
$("#date_time").text(new Date($.now()));
```

suppose the another jsp page :

```
    <body>
            <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
 $(document).ready( function () {
            $("#date_time").text(new Date($.now()));
});
        </body>
```

Comment: in your header.jsp have u included the jquery files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include JavaScript file in partial views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912755/include-javascript-file-in-partial-views)

Comment: It should work but provided that id=date_time must be unique.

Comment: @ Santino 'Sonny' Corleone:
I have included jquery.min.js in the jsp pages,where i am including this header.jsp.

Comment: thank you all for answering. Well , now it is working. I missed <script> tag around it.Thank you once again.

Comment: @edge sad...wat editor u using?notepad?