# dynamically loaded js function does not appear in Firebug js debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, jquery, firebug

There is a page1.html (I open it in browser):

```
<div id="content">
</div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : 'page2.html',
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(response) {          
            jQuery('#content').append(response);

        }
    });
</script>
```

Code of the page2.html:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/page2.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
test();
</script>
```

Code of the page js/page2.js:

```
function test() {
    alert('Function Test()');
}
```

Everything works well, the window "Function Test()" is shown. But the problem is that I can't reach the code of function test() in firebug js debugger. It doesn't appear in event scripts nor in eval.

How can I fix that?

FYI: 
If I don't put the function in separate js file, but place it in page2.html, it 
appears in debugger corectly.

If I put "debugger" word in test() function, Firebug stops, but the source code of the function is still unreachable.

Versions: Firefox 3.0.10, Firebug 1.3.3

Update: pretty much the same as the question [Making Firebug break inside dynamically loaded javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858779/making-firebug-break-inside-dynamically-loaded-javascript), but there is no answer yet

Answer (score 4):

It's a hack, but I got firebug to stop in the external file `js/page2.js` by adding the word debugger twice. Once at the top of the file and another time at the top of the function.

If the debugger word is there only once in either place, firebug does not stop.

```
debugger;
function test() {
    debugger;
    alert('Function Test()');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it indeed stops on "debugger" if I place it anywhere in js/page2.js (I mentioned it in a message), but still I can't get the source code (watch local wars, step by step moving etc)

Comment: By doing exactly what I mentioned in my post, having the debugger word twice, I am able to step through the source and watch local vars.

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. However for more complex functions (like in my real case) it still doesn't work properly ...

Comment: So, we can prove that it works in the simple scenario. Please provide a little more information on your complex case, and what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps, there's a different way of approaching a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change js/page2.js to:

```
function test() {
    alert('Function Test()');
}
alert('loaded');
```

Do you see the "loaded" message?

Comment: Yes, of course, Script execution works correctly, but it is not "loaded" in firebug properly

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
eval('debugger;');
```

It's not pretty but it seems to work.

Comment: Why not just `debugger;`? `eval` seems unnecessary if you pass a static string.