# Firebug - Debugging script loaded dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firebug, jquery-ui-tabs

Using jQuery UI tabs I load pages which contain JavaScript code.
Is there any way using Firebug to debug that code? Can't see then in the 'Scripts' tab of firebug, showing 'all', 'static, eval and event'.

Comment: how about the html tab. you can debug there too

Comment: It doesn't show up there. I'm populating tabs content via AJAX. The html shows up in the 'html' tab, but the associate Javascript doesn't. The JavaScript still runs though.

Comment: Would it depends on how you insert the script to the page? For example if you load from ajax and eval, they should show up in eval.  If you create a script tag to run them, they should show up in html.  Do you have any sample page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, with the keyword `debugger`. I believe it also works with Web Inspector for WebKit-based browsers. So, for example, you can do something like this:

```
a = 1;
debugger;
a = 2;
```

And Firebug should happily break at the line where `debugger` is inserted.

---

There have been several similar questions on SO, as usual:

- [dynamically loaded js function does not appear in Firebug js debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874256/dynamicaly-loaded-js-function-does-not-appear-in-firebug-js-debugger)
- [Making Firebug break inside dynamically loaded javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858779/making-firebug-break-inside-dynamically-loaded-javascript)

I had an experience with an older version firebug/firefox where it did not cope well with the `debugger` keyword. It paused the JavaScript execution all right, but did not show the correct bits of the script, which was kind of useless. But I could still use the console to access the DOM objects and variables, as well as stepping through it blindly.